# C# StackOverFlow Exception during loop by calling same method again

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I have a Console Application, which makes API calls and returns data to console.

I'm using thread to start calling API and calling method to get messages which calls itself in the end. This exemple throws StackOverFlowException. But if I'm using simple while loop instead it works perfect.

Why it throws an StackOverFlowException in first code exemple then two different methods actually do the same work?

```
var thread = new Thread(GetMessagesInternal);
thread.Start();

private static void GetMessagesInternal() { //THROWS STACKOVERFLOWEXCEPTION

    var messages = MyProgram.GetMessages();

    foreach (var message in messages) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{message.MessageText}");
    }

    GetMessagesInternal();
}

    private static void GetMessagesInternal() { //WORKS FINE

    while(true) {

       var messages = MyProgram.GetMessages();

       foreach (var message in messages) {
           Console.WriteLine($"{message.MessageText}");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Google "infinite recursion"

Comment: Sorry, but maybe you should step through your code in a debugger, before you ask the question. You are asking people to take the time to help you. What you can at least do is taking the time to try to figure out yourself what's going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

A method does not finish until it has completed all its operations - including the call to itself. Each time the method calls itself, it pushes the current state onto the stack, so when it returns, it can restore its state.

Do this too often, and you will overflow the stack.

To repeat code indefinitely, you can it in a `while(true)` loop instead.

PS. [IL has a "tail" method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.tailcall(v=vs.110).aspx) that does what you expected your code to do - *complete* the current method and execute another - but it is not included in the C# language.

Comment: Actually ryujit does TCO under some circumstances (there was even a fun bug in the implementation that the SO people found).  So the code could actually behave identical if run with the right options (I'm assuming tco is only done in release).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this.

```
    private static void GetMessagesInternal() //WORKS FINE
{

    while(true)
    {
       var messages = MyProgram.GetMessages();

       foreach (var message in messages)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"{message.MessageText}");
        }
    }
```

This will go in indefinite loop.and GetMessages() method will get called infinite time you need to break this loop at certain condition.

Comment: Uhm, he says it works fine. The issue he has with the other code snippet.

Comment: I was hoping  while (true) will get execute for infinite number as MyProgram.GetMessages() this method will get call infinite time, BTW it works then it doen't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between both snippets is the nesting. If you do a call to yourself, you won't 'exit' until that other call finishes.

Visualized:

```
-->GetMessagesInternal
    --> GetMessagesInternal
        --> GetMessagesInternal
            --> GetMessagesInternal
                --> etc
```

This will flood the stack, every call remains on the stack

And the other one:

```
-->GetMessagesInternal
-->GetMessagesInternal
-->GetMessagesInternal
-->GetMessagesInternal
-->etc
```